# Почему Django может не пускать в админку?

Tags: администрирование, django

Фреймворк `Django` не пускает в админку. При этом не выводит совершенно никаких ошибок. Логин и пароль верны, ошибок авторизации нет. Синхронизация с БД MySQL произведена. С чем это может быть связано?

Comment: Что значит "не пускает"? Что выводит? Что в логах?

Comment: админку не включил значить

Comment: логи - это сообщения в терминале после запуска (python manage.py runserver) ? Можно ли где нибудь еще посмотреть дополнительную информацию?

Comment: на всякий случай с помощью manage.py createsuperuser можете создать еще одного админа и попробовать через него, у меня вот в одном проекте старом ошибок при неправильном пароле/логине вообще не выводит, даже если они не правильны.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

А вы включили админку?

---

1. Добавьте *django.contrib.admin* в параметр **INSTALLED_APPS**. Порядок элементов в **INSTALLED_APPS** не имеет значения.

---

1. Убедитесь, что **INSTALLED_APPS**  содержит *django.contrib.auth, django.contrib.sessions* и *django.contrib.contenttypes*. Интерфейс администратора требует подключения этих трёх пакетов.

---

1. Убедитесь, что **MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES** содержит *django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware* и *django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware* а также *django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware*.

---

Comment: проверил, все изначально было включено. Даже не знаю, что думать

Answer (score 0):

В общем разобрался. Проблема была из-за специфичного стороннего модуля

Answer (score 0):

Аналогичная беда приключилась.
Причина была в установке `SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE = True` на сайте без HTTPS