# Как узнать session_cookie_secure True или False? И где (как) поменять это значение?

Tags: django, python-3.6

Есть сайт на Django. В режиме отладки все работало хорошо. Потом я разместил сайт на хостинге. При запуске сайта с хостинга  все хорошо, но когда я пытаюсь зайти с админки пишут, что пароль неверный. Хостинг не поддерживает https. Полагаю причина в этом. Думаю, что session_cookie_securе = True, поэтому хочу поменять на False, но не знаю как.

Comment: А базу данных, в которой записан пароль, разместили-то? Или каким образом был задан пароль на хостинге?

Comment: Касательно SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE — [оно по умолчанию False](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/settings/#session-cookie-secure); если вы сами собственными руками нигде не задали True, то оно не будет True. И по-моему к ошибке про пароль она не должна иметь значения (при проблемах с кукой сессии скорее будет ошибка про csrf-токен, но точное поведение не проверял)

Comment: да, разместил, sql. С git все на pythonanywhere направил. Я не менял ничего, но другой причины не вижу почему так. Вот тут писали про это https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/314544/218774

Comment: По ссылке всё же «ошибок авторизации нет», что несколько другое. А «пароль неверный» больше намекает на то, что Django его по каким-то причинам не видит в базе. Расскажите подробнее, что вы имеете в виду под словом «sql» и как у вас база настроена. По умолчанию (в стандартном settings.py, если DATABASES в нём никто не редактировал) Django использует файл базы db.sqlite3 в каталоге BASE_DIR (где это на вашем хостинге, я не знаю, вам виднее); соответственно пароль ищется там же

Comment: DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}

Comment: я просто хочу поменять значение SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE

Comment: Если вы хотите просто его поменять, то там же, рядышком с DATABASES, пишите `SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE = False` и всё, только скорее всего это вам не поможет, потому что причина вероятно в чём-то другом

Comment: Лучше покажите полные пути к файлу с вашей базой и к файлу settings.py, вдруг я какую-нибудь опечатку замечу

Comment: db.sqlite3 у меня в .gitignore наверно из-за этого.

Comment: Он и должен быть в .gitignore — ни базы, ни тем более пароли ни в коем случае не должны храниться в гите

Comment: но сайт я размещал с гита прямо оттуда

Comment: Значит базу вы, видимо, всё-таки не разместили. Значит заполните её заново или скопируйте на хостинг вручную без гита. В любом случае гит не задуман для хранения баз или паролей

Comment: да, вы были правы. базу разместил, создал суперюзера и все заработало.